# Javascript change the object name

Tags: javascript, object

is it possible to change the object name in javascript like from this

```
{ 'sep': { 'date' : 'sep', 'likes' : 2}, 'oct' :{ 'date' : 'sep', 'likes' : 2} }
```

to something like that?

```
{'index':{'date':'sep','likes':2}, 'index' :{'date':'sep','likes':2}}
```

Comment: Do you want to have 2 same object names??

Comment: yes, is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible!

Answer (score 5):

Well this is not possible in JSON since 'index' key is repeated twice.

```
{'index':{'date':'sep','likes':2}, 'index' :{'date':'sep','likes':2}}
```

You can better put this in an array. something like this

```
[{'date':'sep','likes':2}, {'date':'sep','likes':2}]
```